# How can I deploy & interact with contract on substrate using rust, not polkadot js?

Tags: ink, rust, substrate-contracts-node

I'm currently trying to deploy & interact with my contract using rust, but I can't find any methods or examples about this. (I've searched paritytech's github) Is there any way to deploy & interact with my contract using rust? (Not by polkadot js) I think I can interact with chain by using subxt or substrate-api-client, but I can't deploy or interact with my contract (Call or Execute my functions)

I appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 2):

There are some examples of working with contracts in the subxt tests (see https://github.com/paritytech/subxt/blob/master/testing/integration-tests/src/frame/contracts.rs#L58).

There's also this Rust based tool which uses subxt and exists to help manage and deploy ink based contracts: https://github.com/paritytech/cargo-contract.

Having a look at said tests, or the cargo-contract code should get you well on your way to using subxt to work with contracts!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @jsdw's suggestions, have a look at https://github.com/paritytech/smart-bench. There I have written a macro which generates code based on a contract's metadata, which can then be used to build messages to send to ink! contracts via subxt.

e.g. https://github.com/paritytech/smart-bench/blob/master/src/wasm/mod.rs#L27

In the future it would be nice to extract that to it's own library so it can be reused, but that likely won't happen for a while so feel free to just copy that code for now.